# C++11 lambda capture list [=] use a reference

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, capture

When I capture a value but the value type is a reference in a template function

```
template<class T>
void test(T&&i)
{
    ++i;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
void typetest(T&& t)
{
    ++t;
    T t1(t);
    [=]() mutable { std::cout << t1 << std::endl; return test(t1); }();
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int i=1;
    typetest(i);
}
```

it prints

```
2
3
2
```

But in `T t1(t);` `T` is `int&` so `t1` should be `int&` when the lambda calls `test(t1)`. Why is the output not

```
2
3
3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> T is int& so t1 should be int&

References are not pointers. `T` may be deduced as `int&`, thus `t1` is a reference. But you asked the lambda to capture `t1` by *value*. That means copying the *value* referenced by `t1`.

If `t1` were a pointer, you would get the pointer by value. But you can't get a reference "by value"; you can only get the value being referenced.

Comment: I test in lambda.  [=]()mutable{mytesttypecode(decltype(t1));return test(t1);}();  and t1 is int&.  something no good I think.....

Answer (score 2):

Through capture-by-value `[=]` your lambda obtains a local copy of `t1` which it passes to `test()`, so whatever happens to `t1` in the lambda will never affect the original `t` object.